# Beck-Chevalley via coend-calculus

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

Consider the following commutative square in $\bf Cat$; strictness can be removed from the initial assumptions, but let's proceed gradually.

[image]

Consider the induced diagram between presheaves

[image]

Beck-Chevalley isomorphism now says that the iso $$k^* f^* \cong h^* g^*$$ (induced by functoriality) induces another isomorphism 
$$h_! k^* \cong g^* f_!,$$ 
namely
$$
\text{Lan}_f(P)\circ g \cong \text{Lan}_h(P\circ k)
$$
for each $P\colon \mathbf{B}\to \bf Set$; I like to rephrase this isomorphism as the isomorphism of coends
$$
\int^B \mathbf{A}(fB, gC)\times PB\cong \int^D \mathbf{C}(hD, C)\times P(kD)
$$

> Is there a way to prove this by coend-fu?

Comment: What? The Beck–Chevalley condition is not automatic.

Comment: Right, I've been too hasty.

Comment: Anyway, the coend calculus is _not_ a good way of verifying the Beck–Chevalley condition. For one thing, the condition is that a _specific_ natural transformation is invertible, not that a natural isomorphism exists, and the coend calculus makes it hard to check that the natural isomorphism you get is the one you want. It should be doable in principle, but I never managed to do it.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned in the comments, the Beck-Chevalley condition is not automatically satisfied; so you won't be able to show $g^* f_{!} \cong h_{!} k^*$. But you can construct a morphism $ h_{!} k^* \to g^* f_{!}$ using coends: For $P : \mathcal{B} \to \mathsf{Set}$, we have:

$$(h_{!} k^*)(P) = \int^{\mathcal{D}} \hom_\mathcal{C}(h(D),-) \times P(k(D))$$
$$(g^* f_{!})(P) = \int^{\mathcal{B}} \hom_\mathcal{A}(f(B),g(-)) \times P(B)$$

First, we have a canonical morphism of functors
$$\hom_\mathcal{C}(h(D),-) \to \hom_{\mathcal{A}}(g(h(D)),g(-)) \cong \hom_\mathcal{A}(f(k(D)),g(-)),$$
which induces a morphism from $(h_{!} k^*)(P)$ to
$$\int^{\mathcal{D}} \hom_\mathcal{A}(f(k(D)),g(-)) \times P(k(D)).$$
But this has an obvious "substitution" morphism to
$$ \int^{\mathcal{B}} \hom_\mathcal{A}(f(B),g(-)) \times P(B),$$
that is, $(g^* f_{!})(P)$. A sufficient condition for $h_{!} k^* \cong g^* f_{!}$ is that $g$ and $k$ are fully faithful, as can be seen directly from the construction above.

By the way, $\mathsf{Set}$ can (should?) be replaced by any cocomplete category and $\mathcal{B},\mathcal{D}$ should be assumed to be small; otherwise $f_{!}$ and $h_{!}$  won't exist (even for $\mathsf{Set}$). Also, in order to construct a morphism of functors $h_{!} k^* \to g^* f_{!}$, we actually don't need $g h \cong f k$ (or even $gh=fk$); a morphism $fk \to gh$ suffices.

Comment: Of course, one can construct the Beck–Chevalley transformation by pasting natural transformations together as well, which is what these manipulations are hiding. Indeed: $$h_! k^* \Rightarrow g^* g_! h_! k^* \Rightarrow g^* f_! k_! k^* \Rightarrow g^* f_!$$

Comment: Yes, this is the usual construction. I am not sure if writing down these morphisms via coends *hides* anything.

Comment: Incidentally, you have a typo: you need a natural transformation $f k \Rightarrow g h$, not the other way around.